# iOS - UIScrollView from half to full screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

In a `UIViewController`, I have a `UIScrollView` that takes half of the screen. This `UIScrollView` contains a collection of `UIView`. On some specific event, such as a swipe, I want my `UIScrollView` to take full screen animatedly, how do I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
// adding swipe gesture to your scrollview
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

// Set swipe direction.
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[scrollview addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];


// add gesture action method
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
// if you are having only one swipe gesture, you no need to add the below condition. you can add the code inside the condition
if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
    scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame;
    scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
}
```

Comment: not working, my `UIScrollView` doesn't change its size at all

Comment: can i know how you set the scrollview. are you using xib or programmatically. if possible can you share snippet of your code

Comment: same code its working for me.. i am able to re-size scrollview on swipe.. can you please check it.

Comment: I was just trying to test so I added the code in viewDidLoad, which for some reason didn't work. But if I tried to add to the event like `handleSwipe` it worked. But is there a way to do this animatedly?

Comment: I think I figured, I used `[UIView beginbeginAnimations:context:]` and `[UIView commitAnimations]`

Comment: bohanl remember to import gesture recogniser delegate, and use [UIView animateWithDuration....] method to animate with blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method on event and set  :

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(847, 800); // change on basis of your requirement
```

For animating scroll view :

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;  // animate at constant velocity to new offset
```

Comment: setting content offset won't change the size of the `UIScrollView`

Comment: Yes ..if you see carefully I have mentioned contentSize for setting and for animation I have said contentOffset

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from @RAJA's answer and slight improvement:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"whatever" context:nil];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * <count of subviews>);
scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Please set contentsize as follows.. scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * <count of subviews>);

Answer (score 0):

I just extend the first answer, If you want animate the above process, you can achieve that by appending the following code :

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe 
 {
   if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) 
    {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15f  // set duration for your animation here
                     animations:^{

                         scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame;
                         scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"completion block");
                     }];

    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to do the same using NSLayoutConstraint just by changing its height using `NSLayoutAttributeHeight`. I know this solution might not be typical but do you see any drawbacks?